# Error when converting py file to exe file using pyinstaller and scipy module. Any idea what could be the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, pyinstaller, py2exe

I am running Python 3.6.4, OS Windows 10 Home 64-bit

This is not the original code that gave me the issue but wrote a very simple one to prove that scipy was giving me the errors.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
print('Hello World')
close_this = input('Press ENTER to close.')
```

I then converted this file (hello.py) to an exe file using the following code below in cmd.

```
pyinstaller -F Hello.py
```

I got multiple warnings. All saying that "lib not found"

```
52530 WARNING: lib not found: libopenblas.JKAMQ5EVHIVCPXP2XZJB2RQPIN47S32M.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ellip_harm_2.cp36-win32.pyd
```

Then I ran my newly created exe file (hello.exe). It flashed for a second and instantly crashed. The error it gave me was that it could not find scipy module.

```
File "Hello.py", line 1, in <module>
...
ImportError: DLL load faild: The specified module could not be found.
```

When I try to convert the python file without line 1 (importing scipy). I get no errors and correctly converts to exe.

This is as far as I got. I appreciate any help given. :)

Comment: Have you tried looking at any of these to see if they are related? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+%22lib+not+found%22 Some answers indicate that it might be a problem with pyinstaller Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply update PyInstaller.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/installation.html